# Why XMLHttpRequest works but Angular2+ returns a 404?

Tags: ajax, angular, http

I'm using angular6.

When `getHello` gets called it returns a 404 error.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class RequisicaoTransporteService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getHello() : Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:17844/api/requisicaotransporte/getHello',{},httpOptions)
    };

}
```

This is how i call it:

```
this.requisicaoTransporteService.getHello()
            .subscribe(x => this.hello = x);
```

[image]
When i do the following, it works fine:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:17844/api/requisicaotransporte/gethello",

success:function(o){console.log(o);}

});
```

The server allows CORS.

Comment: Is your implementation case sensitive? ajax you have lowercase h in `gethello` whereas your other call is capital `getHello`

Comment: Nice catch! I did alter it, but it changes nothing.